# What's FQDN of a WORKGROUP pc?

Tags: domain-name, workgroup, fqdn

What do I enter when asked for FQDN (fully qualified domain name), for a PC that's not in a domain but in a WORKGROUP instead?

Comment: Depends on what's asking.  What's asking?

Comment: @HopelessN00b Lync server installation.  I am trying to install it on a standalone server that can't have domain controller, and I can't join a domain hosted on another server, because it runs 2003.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workgroup computers don't have an FQDN unless you specifically configure them to have one. They have only a NetBIOS (single label) name.

Also, don't confuse the Primary DNS suffix with the DNS suffix search list as assigned by DHCP because they're two different things.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows PCs you can check with:

> ipconfig /all

Giving:

> Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PCNAME
>
> Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : local

FQDN = Hostname + Primary DNS Suffix

So in this case: PCNAME.local

Comment: No, that's actually wrong.  It's only PCNAME.local if your DNS suffix is `local`.

Comment: Obviousbly, when dns DNS suffix is empty, you'll get: PCNAME + null = PCNAME:)

Answer (score 3):

It would be PCNAME.

That's PCNAME plus a dot.